# Jquery selecting elements next/prev/closest

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I have this html and i want to add some actions when user click on h4.

```
<div class="row success">
<div class="col-sm-4 no-pad-r img-toggle">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-1 no-pad-l">
    <h4 class="heading-toggle"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>

    <div class="line"></div>
    <p class="intro">"<?php the_field('first_line'); ?>."</p>

    <div class="toggle-content" style="display: none">
        <div class="main-copy"> <?php the_content(); ?></div>
        <h5><?php the_field('author_name'); ?></h5>

        <p class="position"><?php the_field('author_position'); ?></p>
    </div>
    <button class="btn toggle btn-danger"></button>
</div>
```

So i want to add some classes and slideToggle on click but i cant select proper elements.

This is my attempt.

```
$( ".heading-toggle" ).click(function() {
    $(this).next( ".toggle-content" ).slideToggle();
    $(this).closest( ".success" ).toggleClass( "highlight" );
    $(this).closest( ".toggle" ).toggleClass( "open" );
    });
```

The only thing that works here is adding highlight class to .success div, rest two functions doesn`t work. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Why are you passing a class to `slideToggle()`? Also, I don't see an element with class `heading-toggle` in your HTML. It'll be hard to help you with DOM traversal without the relevant portions of the DOM. (Please post HTML, not PHP.)

Comment: Thanks i have edited my question and added whole html, im not sure how i missed that out, and removed class from slidetoggle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select element on same level use .siblings method
http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

So your code will look like this

```
$( ".heading-toggle" ).click(function() {
    $(this).siblings( ".toggle-content" ).slideToggle();
    $(this).closest( ".success" ).toggleClass( "highlight" );
    $(this).siblings('.btn').toggleClass( "open" );
    });
```